# Getting Specific Data from RDS Automated backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS automated backup from several hours ago. In there is some data, which I have accidentally removed from the current database. Is it possible to extract data from an old automated backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming the data was present at your recovery time.

If you used the [automated backup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) feature, you will be able to [restore a DB instance to a specified time](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html) -- this process will create a new DB instance that uses the data from your backup. Here's a detailed explaination of what would be happening:

> The automated backup feature of Amazon RDS enables point-in-time recovery of your DB Instance. When automated backups are turned on for your DB Instance, Amazon RDS automatically performs a full daily snapshot of your data (during your preferred backup window) and captures transaction logs (as updates to your DB Instance are made). When you initiate a point-in-time recovery, transaction logs are applied to the most appropriate daily backup in order to restore your DB Instance to the specific time you requested.

You haven't told us what type of database engine you're using... but very generally, once the new DB instance is in the available state, you will be able to connect to it and extract any data just as you would on the source DB instance.

You can perform this action from the:

- [AWS console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html)
- CLI ([rds-restore-db-instance-to-point-in-time](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime.html))
- API ([RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime.html)).

Note that the security group will be set to the "Default" group by default, so you may need to modify the DB instance after it becomes available if you use any custom security groups to connect.

Comment: So when I use 'restore a DB instance to a specified time' this will create a new DB instance, rather than reverting the selected RDS to that point in time?

Comment: Yes, and if it puts you at ease you don't have to take my word for it -- [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html) says as much: "You can restore your DB instance to any specific time during this retention period, *creating a new DB instance*."